# AWS SES on Lambda - fails (silently) to send email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use the [amazon-ses](/questions/tagged/amazon-ses) service on a [aws-lambda](/questions/tagged/aws-lambda) in order to send an email to verified recipients.

I'm following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/) simple tutorial which shows a simple [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) function:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

     var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["recipientEmailAddress"]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: { Data: "Test" }
            },
            Subject: { Data: "Test Email" }
        },
        Source: "sourceEmailAddress"
    };

     ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
        callback(null, {err: err, data: data});
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {                
            console.log(data);
            context.succeed(event);
        }
    });
};
```

The following policy is part of the lambda's role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason, **this lambda function fails to send any emails** and it doesn't provide any status information inside the function's CloudWatch Log group:

```
REPORT RequestId: XXX   Duration: 534.59 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 117 MB
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I work in `sandbox-mode` and both *source* and *recipient* are verified emails from the region mentioned in the code (It is also reflected in the logs - no errors being thrown).

---

I Found the following questions in SO - but no relevant answer to my case:

[Sending email via AWS SES within AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608503/sending-email-via-aws-ses-within-aws-lambda-function/41178183)

[AWS SES send email lambda not sending every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495748/aws-ses-send-email-lambda-not-sending-every-time)

[SES email not sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771939/ses-email-not-sending)

[python error sending mail with amazon ses with aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473158/python-error-sending-mail-with-amazon-ses-with-aws-lambda/59112073#59112073)

Comment: Put `callback(null, {err: err, data: data});` to the last, after `else` block to see what will be throw out.

Comment: Seems like the function is getting timed out, have you launched it in VPC ? Try to launch it without VPC ?

Comment: No Timeout - the function returns successfully after 534.59 [ms] (see in the log above).  Launched without VPC.

Comment: any solution here? I suppose not...

Answer (score 1):

I think `context.succeed` is deprecated. Also you can use `async/await`:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

 var params = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["recipientEmailAddress"]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: { Data: "Test" }
        },
        Subject: { Data: "Test Email" }
    },
    Source: "sourceEmailAddress"
};

const data = ses.sendEmail(params).promise()
return data
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. I just tried using your code and it has no problem.

I would recommend you check your identities setting and sandbox-mode.

If you are still in a sandbox-mode, it only allows you to send an email from a verified email address to other verified email addresses.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) documentation will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @pilijoong - Both the source and recipient are verified emails (if one of them wasn't verified , it was reflected in the log).

Comment: Don't you see any other log messages other than the line you posted. Just in case did you check the spam ,junk folders in your email account

Comment: I mean, If there was a problem with the emails not being verified, a relevant error was appearing in the log (Something like Error: The XXX email is not being verified). Anyway, +1 for your answer because your'e pointing out on an important issue.

Comment: And yes, The Spam / Junk folders were checked.